# cURL failed to initialize

Tags: curl, npm

Trying to install npm for node v0.6.2 using

```
$ curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh
```

but encountered error from cURL saying,

```
curl: (2) Failed initialization.
```

I tried cURL other links also, but same error keeps coming. I tried google it, but could not found any good solution to fix this error. Please help me in fixing this or other way to install npm.

P.S. - I use Ubuntu 10.04 and I had npm configured earlier, but uninstalled it.

Comment: I'm not sure why cURL won't work or I'd answer, but wget is a pretty solution as well. "wget http://npmjs.org/install.sh"

Comment: @cabbagebot - Tried Copying the npm-install.sh file you specified in a local file and executed it. Looks like installation file also uses cURL for installation.

Comment: Sorry I missed this. I assume the script then fails to initialize cURL as well?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the curl and got the following response.

```
<html>Moved: <a href="https://npmjs.org/install.sh">https://npmjs.org/install.sh</a>
```

It looks like they moved the file to an https server.

So then you need to run curl on the link url that is provided using:

```
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh > install.sh
```

This will send the result to a file.called install.sh